# Airflow GCSToBigQueryOperator task failing in schema update options

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I've written the below airflow composer code to load the parquet files from GCS bucket into BigQuery table using GCSToBigQueryOperator task but it is failing with the error "google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Schema update options should only be specified with WRITE_APPEND disposition, or with WRITE_TRUNCATE disposition on a table partition". As per the airflow documentation, we can only use WRITE_TRUNCATE disposition attribute if the table is partition and i am already partitioning the BigQuery Table
using attribute time_partitioning where i am specifying that i want the partition column to be "date_updated". I want to use WRITE_TRUNCATE only and not WRITE_APPEND.Please help me out what am i doing wrong.I am using Airflow version 2.4.3 on GCP Composer 2.1.8

Here is my code -

```
from airflow import DAG
import pandas as pd
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
from airflow.models import Variable
import re
import numpy as np

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 3, 15),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG('extract_mysql_table_gcs_bq_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
    catchup=False
)

source_objects_path = Variable.get('output_path')
gcs_bucket = 'test-bucket'
project_id = 'test'
bq_dataset = 'bronze'

def extract_latest_mysql_table_parquet_files():
    from google.cloud import storage
    # Create a client object for the GCS bucket
    client = storage.Client()

    bucket = client.get_bucket('test-bucket')

    latest_folder_name = None
    latest_timestamp = 0
    folder_name='mysql_table/'
    print(f'list of blobs is {bucket.list_blobs}')

    for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder_name):
        print(f'blob value is {blob}')
        if blob.name.endswith('/'):  # Check if it is a folder
            print(f'the blob name is {blob.name}')
            # folder_match = re.match('^mysql_table\/mysql_table_\d{8}_\d{6}\/$', blob.name)
            folder_match = re.match('^(mysql_table/mysql_table_\d{8}_\d{6}/)$', blob.name)
            print(f"folder_match is {folder_match}")
            if folder_match:
                folder_name = folder_match.group(1)
                if folder_name.endswith('/'):
                  folder_name = folder_name[:-1]  # remove trailing slash
                folder_timestamp = int(folder_name.split('_')[-2] + folder_name.split('_')[-1])
                if folder_timestamp > latest_timestamp:
                    latest_folder_name = folder_name
                    latest_timestamp = folder_timestamp

    if latest_folder_name is not None:
        print(f'latest folder name is {latest_folder_name}')
        parquet_files = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=f'{latest_folder_name}/'))
        parquet_files = [blob.name for blob in parquet_files if blob.name.endswith('.parquet')]
        print(f"the parquet files are {parquet_files}")
        if len(parquet_files) == 0:
            raise Exception('No Parquet files found in the latest timestamp folder')

        # Read the Parquet files into a list of DataFrames
        dfs = [pd.read_parquet(f'gs://test-bucket/{file}') for file in parquet_files]

        print(f'list of dataframe is {dfs}')

        # return dfs
        return dfs, latest_folder_name
    else:
        return []

def export_mysql_table_parquet_files():
    dfs, latest_folder_name = extract_latest_mysql_table_parquet_files()

    print(f'the list containing dataframes is {dfs}')
    print(f'my latest folder name is {latest_folder_name}')
    print(f'dfs[0] value is {dfs[0]}')

    if not dfs[0].empty:
        # Combine the DataFrames into one
        df = pd.concat(dfs)
        df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
        output_path = f'gs://test-bucket/{latest_folder_name}/mysql_table_combined.parquet'
        df.to_parquet(output_path)
        source_objects_path = f"{latest_folder_name}/mysql_table_combined.parquet"
    else:
        source_objects_path = ""

    print(f'source_objects_path value is {source_objects_path}')    
    Variable.set('source_objects_path', source_objects_path)
    print(f"data exported successfully in parquet format combined")

# export the list of Parquet files for mysql_table table.
mysql_table_export_files = PythonOperator(
        task_id='mysql_table_export_files',
        python_callable=export_mysql_table_parquet_files,
        provide_context=True,dag=dag)

mysql_table_export_to_bq_staging = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='mysql_table_export_to_bq_staging',
    bucket=gcs_bucket,
    source_objects=Variable.get('source_objects_path'),
    destination_project_dataset_table=f'{bq_dataset}.mysql_table_stg$date_updated',
    schema_fields=[
      {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "INTEGER"
      }
      {
        "name": "date_updated",
        
        "type": "TIMESTAMP"
      }
                    ],
    schema_update_options=["ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION"],
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    time_partitioning={
    'type': 'DAY',
    'fields': 'date_updated'
                      },
    source_format='PARQUET',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    dag=dag
)

mysql_table_export_files >> mysql_table_export_to_bq_staging
```